# React native notifications in a Chat App

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm working on a chat application and I currently have 6 different chat channels with a different firebase database for each of them. Every channels have firebase rules that define if an user can read and write in this channel. I want to send notifications to users when a new message is posted, but only the users that are part of the specified channel.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const _ = require('lodash');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/GeneralMessage').onWrite(event => {
    const getValuePromise = admin.database()
                                 .ref('GeneralMessage')
                                 .orderByKey()
                                 .limitToLast(1)
                                 .once('value');

    return getValuePromise.then(snapshot => {
        console.log(_.values(snapshot.val())[0]);
        const { text } = _.values(snapshot.val())[0];

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'New msg',
                body: text,
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging()
                    .sendToTopic('GeneralMessage', payload);
    });
});
```

That's the code I currently have using firebase cloud function in `/functions/index.js`. When I send a message in the app, I have this output in firebase : [Firebase cloud functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vket2.png) but the notifications isn't working in app.